# What does "my pronouns" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw that phrase on someone's post on Facebook. I think it's not appropriate to talk about the detail source (screenshot) in which I found that phrase. To be precise, it says:

> My pronouns are he/him

Did he refer to his gender or what? And if I'm not mistakenly remember, I've seen also someone says my pronouns are she and he. I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these days where gender-fluidity is a thing, it is often unclear what specific gender some people identify themselves as. It is often important for emotional and psychological reasons that they are addressed by the pronouns which match their personal identity, and to ensure this is the case, they announce to the world how they prefer to be addressed.

Hence:

- My pronouns are he/him

tells people that the person identifies as male, and therefore wish to be referred to by male-identification pronouns.

But as for someone who says their pronouns are "she and he", I haven't a clue.

Comment: "She/he" would just be a person who is fine with either pronoun. It's also not unusual for some people to specify the pronoun "they," when they don't identify with "she" or "he."

Comment: The pronouns are not given as she and he. They are given as she/her and he/him. Also, there are a bunch you have not mentioned here. I suggest you update your answer with more of them. :)

Comment: @Lambie That's all the pronouns that were mentioned in the question. I was explaining the philosophy behind the context, not providing an exhaustive list. If you believe the latter is what is required, then I'd be happy to delete my answer as irrelevant.

Comment: @Lambie While "he/him" is currently the most common format, some people just say "he", and others say "he/him/his" rather than "he/him". It's certainly not a rule yet